# Which is correct by 5:00pm or at 5:00pm?

Tags: prepositions, time

Which one of the sentences below is correct?

1. Please be ready **by** 5:00pm.
2. Please be ready **at** 5:00pm.
3. Please be ready **on** 5:00pm.

I'm really confused about this.

Can anyone explain all the sentences above please?

Answer (score 3):

I will rather ask: *Which one of the sentences below **is not correct**?*

Unlike the very last one, the first and second ones (Please be ready by 5:00pm. and Please be ready at 5:00pm.) are both correct.

Take a look at the examples below:

- She said to me: please be ready by 5:00pm.

In the sentence above, *by* 5:00pm connotes *latest by*, meaning: ***before 5:00pm***.

- She said to me: please be ready at 5:00pm.

Here, *at* 5:00pm translates into being ready at that very point in time, either: ***exactly 5:00pm***.

- She said to me: please be ready on 5:00pm.

In the last instance above, the sentence is grammatically wrong because the use of the preposition *on* is **not** appropriate.

*In general, the preposition **on** is often used for places and or locations.*

There is really no definite rule nor formula for choosing a preposition and this can be a tremendous challenge for English language learners.

Answer (score 2):

Usually we use **at** with:

- Clock times: "at 5:00 pm"
- Mealtimes: "at breakfast"

We use **in** with:

- Seasons of the Year
- Years
- Months
- Part of the day

We use **on** with:

- Days
- Dates

We use **by** to express the end point of one activity

If you say be ready by 5:00 pm, it is the end time, not later than 5:00 pm.
Be ready at 5:00 pm is the correct expression (clock times).
Be ready on 5:00 pm is not correct: no days, nor dates after on.

[English-Club Prepositions of Time](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm)